# Find people at image

Tags: algorithm, image-processing, machine-learning, pattern-recognition

I need to implement algorithm which for input has picture ( jpeg ) and create new picture like output, but only with bodies ( background is removed completely ). Input picture is picture with people from vacation and I need to recognize human bodies and remove background. Can someone suggest me what algorithm to use, what book to buy to learn that algorihms ?

Comment: Good luck.  With all the different sizes, shapes, and colors of people...  Even with good image editing software available now it takes a trained yet to do it.  There are some things a computer can't do well (yet) that a human brain can.  If it were that easy, movie makers wouldn't need green screens any more.

Comment: If you are supposed to do that on your own you might as well shoot yourself.

Comment: I also have this requirement in some other field(Where the points in the graph has to be extracted & a new graph should be made). But yeah I like to have some knowledge.

Comment: H.B.'s comment is hilarious, but this is a semi-solvable problem.

In addition to the Szelinski book, **Digital Image Processing** by Gonzalez and Woods is a good introductory textbook for image processing.

Comment: It shows how much there is to learn on the subject if the introductory textbook is 976 pages :)

Answer (score 4):

Check this [link](http://blogs.mathworks.com/steve/2010/10/08/the-two-amigos/) it will perfectly answer your question of removing the background and performing further processing

Answer (score 1):

neural networks are particuarly useful for this kind of task, but the theory is a universe, if you're doing it from scratch ... that's a lot of work

Answer (score 1):

This is a segmentation problem. In the general case, segmenting images is a hard research problem (I just spent five years doing a doctorate on segmenting greyscale medical images, for example) and the way you go about it is strongly tied to the type of images with which you have to deal. The best advice I can give is to go and read the appropriate literature on segmenting colour images (e.g. use Google Scholar). In terms of books, this one's a good general-purpose introduction to image processing:

http://www.amazon.co.uk/Digital-Image-Processing-Rafael-Gonzalez/dp/0130946508/ref=sr_1_7?ie=UTF8&qid=1326236038&sr=8-7

Searching for "segmenting people in colour images" on Google seems to turn up some good links, incidentally.

Answer (score 1):

I have a question for you: you want to implement this using an algorithm? If so, then it might require a lot of things to be done (provided you are new to the field of image processing).
Otherwise you may try using masking techniques in image editing software like Adobe Photoshop (that would hardly take 15 mins, depending upon how well you know it)

A good book to start with image processing techniques is: "Digital Image Processing" by Gonzalez and Woods; it starts from the basics, and explains stuff in depth.

Still it may take a lot of time to develop an algorithm to do this job. I recommend you use some library for the same. OpenCV(opensource computer vision) is an excellent choice. The library itself comes with demos which include programs for face detection etc. The inbuilt functions provide a variety of features (edge detection/Feature identification and extraction, you may have to use this)  Here's the link
http://opencv.willowgarage.com/wiki/

The link provides a lot of reference material that you can make use of! :)

Answer (score 1):

Start with facial recognition software and algorithms; they have been the most refined over the years and as long as all of your bodies have heads, you can use exif data to figure image capture orientation (of course you can't completely rely on that), sample the facial skin to get skin tone ranges, and find the attached body. Anything that is not head and body should be deleted. This process *assumes* that a person has *roughly* the same skin tone on their face as their body and the camera flash isn't washing this out. You could grab the flash duration and some other attributes from exif and adjust your ranges accordingly.

A lot of software out there can recognize faces (look at iPhoto for example), so you'll have to use the face as a reference point, along with skin tone, to find your body edges. You result isn't going to be perfect, but as long as your approach is sound, you'll end up with something useful.

And release your software as open source when you're done so I can use it... :)

Answer (score 1):

You can download a free PDF of the book Computer Vision by Richard Szeliski from the author's website. Not only do you have a free book on algorithms, but it's a book that addresses this specific problem.

http://szeliski.org/Book/

You'll see this image at the top of that page of the author's website.

[image: Image from Szeliski book]

Used copies of the hardcover are available for about $62 if you check addall.com. If you spent some time doing image processing, you'll appreciate having a paper copy of at least one good general reference book.

Answer (score 0):

Its tough but not impossible. I can't give you any code but Peter Norvig had a great talk on the value of data and in the talk he shows how he was able to take a picture of lake and remove all the houses blocking the image and have the lake expanded with boats,etc..

The computer basically learned how lakes look and boats go on lakes and then removed the houses and placed it there.  He explains his process(but no code or anything).

Here it is:
Peter Norvig - The Unreasonable Effectiveness of Data
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yvDCzhbjYWs